# any way to simulate OUTPUT clause in SQl Server Compact 3.5?

Tags: sql, .net-3.5, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I am implementing a Email Queue system. the basic idea is to store emails in the sql ce Db and then read them through a Windows Service and send them.

Assuming that there are 200 rows in the DB i need to fetch 10 records first and so i needed the OUTPUT clause so that i could run something like this

```
UPDATE MAILQUEUE Set STATUS='Fetched' where QueueID in (select top(10) QueueID from MailQueue where Status='Queued' order by QueueID asc)

**OUTPUT** deleted.*
```

if this is not possible i can also think of removing the rows permanently from the DB and processing them and incase of failure store them in a FailQueue table. In this case can Select and Delete be done using the SqlCeTransaction class????

If there is a better way to implement this please advise.

Thanking all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing your SELECT and UPDATE in a single SqlCeTransaction would do the trick.